# Create array from an array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an an array of tags linked to an article which contains nested objects:

`[ {id: 1, name: {"en": "Tag 1" }}, {id: 2, name: {"en": "Tag 2" }}, {id: 3, name: {"en": "Tag 3" }} ]`

I want to create a new array which simply shows the tag name is a single array:

`[Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3]`

I created the following method:

```
var tagNames = [];
  this.article.tags.forEach(value => {
    tagNames.push(Object.values(value["name"]));
  });
console.log(tagNames);
```

However, this creates an array of arrays:

```
[[Tag 1],[Tag 2],[Tag 3]]
```

How can I achieve the single array I want?

Comment: `article.tags.map(item => item.name.en)`

Answer (score 2):

you can replace :

```
tagNames.push(Object.values(value["name"]));
```

by

```
tagNames = [...tagNames,...Object.values(value["name"])];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that.

```js
let data = [ {id: 1, name: {"en": "Tag 1" }}, {id: 2, name: {"en": "Tag 2" }}, {id: 3, name: {"en": "Tag 3" }} ];

let tags = data.map(item => item.name.en);

console.log(tags);
```

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) creates an array of values. So, in your code you could use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the result to desired format.

```js
let data = [ {id: 1, name: {"en": "Tag 1" }}, {id: 2, name: {"en": "Tag 2" }}, {id: 3, name: {"en": "Tag 3" }} ];

var tagNames = [];

data.forEach(value => {
  tagNames.push(Object.values(value["name"]));
});

console.log(tagNames.flat());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the object and take `en` only for mapping.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: { en: "Tag 1" } }, { id: 2, name: { en: "Tag 2" } }, { id: 3, name: { en: "Tag 3" } }],
    result = data.map(({ name: { en } }) => en);

console.log(result);
```